# Use of undefined constant on date

Tags: php

I am not sure why i get the following notice:
 `Notice: Use of undefined constant   - assumed ' '`

if i do `error_reporting(0)` the `notice` disappears and everything works fine. please help me solve this.

Same error on `godaddy PHP v5.4` & `Win-8.1x64 xampp php v5.6.8`
This is only code in my file. nothing more.

```
<?php echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime('2015-05-16 06:06:54')); ?>

<?php echo "<br>"; ?>

<?php echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime('2015-05-16 06:06:54')); ?> //line 5
```

outputs:

```
05-16-2015
05-16-2015
Notice: Use of undefined constant   - assumed ' ' in D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 5
```

[image]

Comment: All I can say is that it works fine in PHP 5.3.1. Which line is line 5?

Comment: Please describe "this is happening." What is happening that is strange?

Comment: @Bsienn Much better. It may also help to include your PHP version.

Comment: @Anonymous i did include my php version, i have tested them on both online godaddy=>v5.4 & xampp=>v5.6.8

Comment: @Bsienn Whoops, my mistake.

Comment: its works fine on my local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a space like character like a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (`U+00A0`).

You could try removing and re-adding all the spaces on line 5.